# Get Only Integers Before and after Certain "Character's" Jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I am in kind of rush what i need to solve is described below

I have a string Like DropDown1_2_3_4 or radioButton2_4_6_8

I need to get Result like: 1,2,3,4 or 2,4,6,8

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var main = id;
main = main.substring(main.indexOf('_') + 1).replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
```

This gives me 234 or 468
What i need is 1,2,3,4 or 2,4,6,8

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using lookahead assertion:

```
'DropDown1_2_3_4'.match(/\d+(?=_)|_\d+/g).map(function(x) { return x.replace('_', ''); })
// => ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
'radioButton2_4_6_8'.match(/\d+(?=_)|_\d+/g).map(function(x) { return x.replace('_', ''); })
// => ["2", "4", "6", "8"]
```

---

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var main = id.match(/\d+(?=_)|_\d+/g).map(function(x) { return x.replace('_', ''); });
```

Javascript regular expression does not support lookbehind assertion.

Comment: Correct, dear anything if I want to save these comma separated id's in separate variables ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to separate them as variables then it is best to use an array

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var main = id;
var main = id.replace(/^[\D]+/i, '').split('_')
alert(main[0])//1,2,3 etc
```

Comment: Yes, It worked fine.
A little more what if I want to save all these ',' separated id's in separate variables ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this,

```
var id = $(this).attr('id'); //'DropDown1_2_3_4';
var main = id;
main = main.replace( /^\D+/g, '').replace(/_/g,',');
alert(main);
```

Demo 1: http://jsfiddle.net/DK8Kk/

```
var id = 'DropDown1_2_3_4';
var main = id;   
main = main.replace( /^\D+/g, '').split('_');
alert(main);
for (var i in main) {
    alert(main[i]);
}
```

Demo 2: http://jsfiddle.net/DK8Kk/2/

Comment: Yes, It worked fine. A little more what if I want to save all these ',' separated id's in separate variables ?